# Incremental dbt model

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt, incremental-build

I have a website with many different `products` for sale and a table `clicks` with all the clicks on the different products.

| click_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |
| 2 | 0023 |
| 3 | 1234 |

1. My products are not available every day.
2. The only way I have to know if a product exists if is someone clicks on it and it appears in the table.

Knowing which products were available at some moment is easy.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM clicks
```

But this is a very big query and I can't afford to do it everyday.

What I want is to maintain a list of historical products and for each new day, knowing which one are available today, with the flag `is_available=1`

I tried using incremental models in dbt but I could not manage to make it work.

1. look at the clicked products today,
2. add products that I never saw before with the flag is_available=1
3. update the availability status of the product depending if they were clicked today. I need to check that hourly.

How can I do this ?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key=['product_id'],
    )
}}

WITH 
    online_products AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            product_id,
            1 AS is_available,
            CURRENT_DATE() AS updated_at
        FROM
            clicks
        WHERE
            partition_date >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    )

SELECT DISTINCT
    product_id
    function_to_update(is_online),
    function_to_update(updated_at)
FROM
    {{ this }} current
{% if is_incremental() %}
FULL OUTER JOIN
    online_products
USING product_id
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What did you try with incremental models and what didn't work? Do you have any code you can post with the errors? Generally speaking, the correct solution would be to write an incremental model that produces a daily periodic fact table for product clicks.

Comment: I have edited my question with some code to show you what I tried.
My first problem is the generation of the historical table, the one that is going to be updated daily